# What is the payload of a richLinkData in Apple Business Chat

Tags: ios, apple-business-chat

I am trying to send a richLink with the Apple Business Chat [Sandbox](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/businesschat/). However I am not able to find out what the correct payload is. The sandbox does not provide a predefined payload for a richLink. Therefore I am using the RAW JSON tab in order to send a richLink.

The example from the apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/businesschat/sending_messages/sending_rich_link_messages) is not working and I think there are certain parts missing. Does anyone know what information is missing?

```
{
   "richLinkData": {
     "url": "https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro",
     "title": "iPad Pro",
     "assets": {
        "image": {
           "data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA…………<snipped>…………AAQAB/Z",
           "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the method they use in this video? It was published Jul 5 2018. It could be that they did not yet update the documentation. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/205/

Answer (score 2):

The example Apple provides is only part of the solution. You must include the additional parameters that are required in an iMessage. The other required parameters are:

> id
>
> sourceId
>
> destinationId
>
> v
>
> type

The different types can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/businesschat/sending_messages/sending_a_message_to_business_chat?language=objc), but for richLinkData we set it to `richLink`.

Here is an example with all the necessary parameters minus the `data` parameter.

```
    {
"v": "<populated on send>",
"id": "<populated on send>",
"sourceId": "<populated on send>",
"destinationId": "<populated on send>",
"richLinkData": {
    "url": "https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro",
    "title": "iPad Pro",
    "assets": {
        "image": {
            "data": "",
            "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
        }
    }
},
"type": "richLink"}
```

Copying and pasting this exactly won't work on it's own. You'll need to fill in the `data` parameter. The `data` field they provide won't work, because it has been truncated. To use an image of your choice, you will need to fill the data field with the base64 encoding of your image. You can go [here](https://www.base64-image.de) to encode your image, but any base64 image encoder will work. You'll want to cut out `data:image/jpeg;base64,` because that portion is written for `<img>` elements. If you don't care about having an image, you can just delete the entire `assets` parameter.